# MITM against NTRU

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, modular-arithmetic, ntru, collision-attack

In MITM attacks against the NTRU cryptosystem, we exploit the fact that in the ring of truncated polynomials of degree $n-1$ it holds that $$fg=h\mod q$$  for our secret and public keys $f,h$. The basic idea is splitting $f$ into $f_1,f_2$ such that $f_1+f_2=f$ and therefore considering $$f_1h=g-f_2h. $$This is *almost* like finding a collision in the function $f(x)=xh$, if it weren't for the presence of $g$. So we must introduce an auxiliary function $a(x)$, which according to the notes I'm reading is defined as follows:

> To search for near-collisions an auxiliary function $a(x)$ is needed.
> This function takes a vector of length n and in each coordinate $x_i$
> returns $\mathbb I (x_i > 0)$. If $g$ does not cause the coordinates
> of $−f_2 · h$ to change sign, i.e. $a(−f_2 · h) \ne a(−f_2 · h + g)$,
> we have that $a(f_1 h) = a(−f_2 h)$.

I don't quite understand what this function is supposed to do. Can anyone explain it to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really give more context. Your quote is the same as in page 3 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/177.pdf.

The function detects positive coordinates.

So, if you apply $a$ to the vector $x$ via
$$
(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=a(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
$$
by definition we have
$$
y_i=\mathbb I (x_i > 0)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccr} 1,&\mathrm{ if} & x_i>0,\\ 0, &\mathrm{ if}& x_i\leq 0.
 \end{array}\right.
$$
For example if $x=(-2,0,3)$ with $n=3,$ then $y=(0,0,1).$

I will expand the claim in the quote (which is a bit loosely phrased) as follows:

If *adding* $g$ does not cause the coordinates
of $−f_2 · h$ to change sign, i.e. *if we do not have* $a(−f_2 · h) \ne a(−f_2 · h + g)$, we have that $a(f_1 h) = a(−f_2 h)$.

In page 2 of the paper, it is also stated that $g$ is chosen with coefficients zero and 1 only. Therefore the two quantities being unequal $a(−f_2 · h) \ne a(−f_2 · h + g)$ when $g$ is added is can just be detected by checking signs since the difference $g$ by design has only $0,1$ coefficients.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the last paragraph? I find it a bit confusing. I would also be very grateful if you could also explain a bit more why this whole method works; it's not so clear to me (following the same notes you link to) why we can 'almost' sure to have found the original key...